# Blocking Proxy Users

Tags: proxy, ip, blacklist

A very simple question..

Im looking for a HTTP Proxy list that is monitorized/uptodate and can be downloaded as
xml,csv, or anything for that matter..

Basically, we have services which we would like to block access too, by known proxies..
We can then Blacklist Proxy IP's for certain functions of our servers.. Or tell the user to identify themselves..

*For example, Gmail Email Registration is monitored by Google for this exact same thing..*

Can anyone help with a well maintained and monitored list, which i can use to black list IP's.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out MaxMind which has a [proxy detection list](http://www.maxmind.com/app/proxy). Since it is always updated it is not downloadable but it queried via a number of protocols. You can read up on their service here.

Note that this is never going to be 100% accurate. I could set up a proxy in 2 seconds using any host with ssh enabled. This will cover the 'big players' of the proxy world.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean regarding accuracy..
However im looking for a free list without service/usage fee's..

I would imagine some "organisation" maintains this.. :/